# python function for loop in dictonary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to retrieve all items from a specific key in a dictionary. The code works, but I keep receiving a `None` statement in the output from my function `general_info`. The other function `specific_info` works normally. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

```
countries = {
"canada": {
    'name': "Canada",
    'location': "North America",
    'currency': "Canadian Dollar",
    'capital city': "Ottawa",
    'population': "32.268.240",
    'area': "9.970.610 km2"
},
"brazil": {
    'name': "Brazil",
    'location': "South America",
    'currency': "Brazilian Real",
    'capital city': "Brasilia",
    'population': "186.404.900",
    'area': "8.514.877 km2"
},
"ukraine": {
    'name': "Ukraine",
    'location': "Europe",
    'currency': "Ukrainian Hryvnia",
    'capital city': "Kyiv",
    'population': "46.480.700",
    'area': "603.700 km2"
},
"haiti": {
    'name': "Haiti",
    'location': "North America",
    'currency': "Haitian Gourde",
    'capital city': "Port-au-Prince",
    'population': "8.527.777",
    'area': "27.750 km2"
},
"albania": {
    'name': "Albania",
    'location': "Europe",
    'currency': "Albanian Lek",
    'capital city': "Tirana",
    'population': "3.129.678",
    'area': "28.748 km2"
},
"india": {
    'name': "India",
    'location': "Asia",
    'currency': "Indian Rupee",
    'capital city': "New Delhi",
    'population': "1.103.371.000",
    'area': "3.287.263 km2"


 }
}

def general_info(c_name):
    for key, val in countries[c_name].items():
        info = print(c_name.title() + " " + key + " is " + val)
    return info

def specific_info(c_name, info):
    if c_name in countries and info in countries[c_name].keys():
        return (info.title() + " from " + c_name.title() + " is " + countries[c_name][info])


ask_country = input("Country name: ")

ask_info = input("Information requested: ")

c_name = ask_country.lower()

info = ask_info.lower()

print(general_info(c_name))
print()
print(specific_info(c_name, info))
```

Comment: The return is in an `if`. Could you imagine a situation where the `if` statement would evaluate to `False`?

Comment: Hi Mad, thanks for helping. So the function using if is working correctly, I didn't implement in case of a false statement yet. My problem is in the first function (general_info) the one using a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code below:

```
def general_info(c_name):
    for key, val in countries[c_name].items():
        # overwrites info in every iteration
        # you are saving return value of print function
        info = print(c_name.title() + " " + key + " is " + val)  
    return info  # return only last iteration "info"

def specific_info(c_name, info):
    if c_name in countries and info in countries[c_name].keys(): # you can simply write info in countries[c_name]. No need of ".keys()" method
        return (info.title() + " from " + c_name.title() + " is " + countries[c_name][info])
```

To return general info you should do as follows:

```
def general_info(c_name):
    general_info = []
    for key, val in countries[c_name].items():
        info = (c_name.title() + " " + key + " is " + val)
        general_info.append(info )
    return general_info
```

Also to format strings, you should try [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) function. I would re-write info as:

```
info = "{country}: {key} is {val}".format(country=c_name.title(), key=key, val=val)
```

This makes you code more readable and easy to write as well.

Comment: Thank you! The string formatted is missing one parenthesis by the way. It was really helpful anyways. Thanks again! 

`info = ("{country}: {key} is {val}".format(c_name.title(), key, val))`

Comment: thanks, corrected it now. would you also like to upvote my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the return value of a print statement, which is always None. Just remove the print.